# Transform ByteArray to java.lang.Object in one step

Tags: mule, dataweave

[image]What is the purpose of ByteArrayToObject if it returns String?

In my flow, i am reading  Json content from a file using mule requester, converting to java.lang.Object before data weave by doing the below 3 steps
  (1) ByteArrayToString 
  (2) ObjectToJSON 
  (3) JSONTOObject

I would like to combine the above 3 steps to one using ByteArrayToObject transformer but as per the documentation, ByteArrayToObject returns String

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/using-transformers

Is there a way to combine the 3 steps to 1 step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert your payload into *java.lang.Object* because it already is an instance of *java.lang.Object*. In Java, all objects inherit of [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html?is-external=true): *Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass*,

If you are reading JSON content from a file and you want to convert the content into some class instance, say *com.mycompany.Apple*, you can directly use the JSONToObject Transformer, specifying the *returnClass* parameter

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.mycompany.Apple" doc:name="JSON to Apple"/>
```

You may want to take a look at the [native Json support documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/native-support-for-json)

The ByteArrayToObject can be used in two fashions, according to the documentation:

- If the byte array is a serialized Java Object, then you can deserialize it into this Object using the *returnClass* parameter.
- If it is not a serialized Object, then it will be transformed into a String

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one Java component for transform the payload